# Update user table on login without touching vendors folder laravel 5.1

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to update a database column which contains the last login every time a user logs in. Is there a way to do this without touching the vendors folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever user tries to login observe the auth.login event and update the user's last login time.
Take a look at [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/events)

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user) {
    $user->last_login = new DateTime;

    $user->save();
});
```

Comment: Thanks that was a good idea. I used an event listener and used the `Model Update Function`.